# Existence and uniqueneess of functional maximizing value on specific element of $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Given a function $f\in L^p$ with $1<p<\infty$ and $\|f\|_p=1$ is it true that there is a unique function $g \in L^q$ with $\|g\|_q=1$ such that $\int fg =1$? This is over an arbitrary measure space.

Comment: Generaly true in any Banach space. This is a consequence of Banach Alaoglu Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because $L^q$, which is the dual of $L^p$, is [strictly convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80139/why-is-the-l-p-norm-strictly-convex-for-1p-infty) for $1<q<\infty$ (actually, it’s uniformly convex). Then you can conclude by the statement contained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344631/prove-that-if-the-dual-space-is-strictly-convex-then-the-duality-map-contains-a).

P.s. Moreover, $g=\operatorname{sgn}(f)|f|^{p-1}$ a.e. (you can verify that the $L^q$ norm is $1$ and $\int fg=1$).